# Best puzzles of 2022 Q2 (April - June)

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of)*

---

> What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the second quarter ( April / May / June ) 2022?

---

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

> **Algorithmically selected "best of":**
>
> - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2022 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2022&month=4#query-results)
> - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2022 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2022&month=4#query-results)
>
> **Best by votes/views:**
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2022 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/04/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2022 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/04/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2022 Q2](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/04/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

<sub>Q: Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>
<sub>A: Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13653/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-first-quarter-2022) do something very similar.</sub>

<sub>Q: What's the point?</sub>
<sub>A1: To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
<sub>A2: To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
<sub>A3: To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 12):

## [I got ninety-nine problems - so here's another one!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116277/i-got-ninety-nine-problems-so-heres-another-one) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)

Lets get one underway, shall we?...

This massive meta-puzzle to celebrate Stiv's 100th puzzle on this site is something we should remember. Stiv is a user who has contributed many well-designed puzzles, and his 100th puzzle was a masterpiece. As Stiv himself has said, this was quite hard to make:

> "Well, it's taken me several months of devising, formatting, testing and re-testing, but I am delighted to be able to present this to you all at last. A huge thank you to all at Puzzling for interacting with my previous puzzles, and I hope you enjoy this one too :)"

What stands out towards me immediately is how Stiv has integrated all his previous puzzles (namely the 10th, 20th, 30th, 40th, 50th, 60th, 70th, 80th and 90th puzzles) by using the original puzzle idea of these puzzles in the metapuzzle. A well-created and well-thought puzzle is a puzzle to be remembered, and it comes with no doubt that this masterpiece tops the boards in highest amounts of votes, and is at the top in views. Plus, it is not only me who thinks this is a very well-created puzzle. A comment from Deusovi:

> Ooh, exciting! Can't believe it's already been 100 puzzles...

and Dertereuui  Floireiurtrthr:

> This is a brilliant puzzle! You truly are an inspiration :-)!

(don't forget the 51 people who upvoted the puzzle)...

All in all, a brilliant meta-puzzle from Stiv, to celebrate his 100th puzzle. And done in fashion...

I hope you continue your high quality puzzle Stiv. They are a very nice addition to the site as a whole, as you edge closer and closer to the 100k mark... :)

Comment: I can't help myself but add that the puzzle's answer was the same as one of my puzzles a long time back... :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [days are determined](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116039/days-are-determined) by [IAmLucidNonsense](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/75052/iamlucidnonsense) and ["Since his](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116043/since-his) by [noneuclideanisms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22856/noneuclideanisms)

Those two puzzles just have to be together as one nomination, might as well.

What first seems like a simple "answer the definition" turned out to be a lot more than one might have bargained for! I was not there for the "big reveal" of the puzzle, but I did see them in order, and when I saw the second puzzle, there was that moment, a moment of happiness almost, everything gets revealed, and it just hits well.

As Stiv mentioned in the comments of the latter "It's beatiful", and I think it is indeed, not only is it good to see two Puzzling members cooperate to create puzzles, but also to see how well the puzzle was received.

It might not have been the most groundbreaking puzzle of the quarter, but it holds a special place up there nonetheless, it makes new with the old, and sometimes that's all that's needed to make a wonderful puzzle.

Also, as Glorfindel pointed out, maybe this is the work of a single mind (the usernames of both authors are anagrams of each other!), and no matter the truth, I think it's a brilliant puzzle that filled my daily puzzling intake, and I really wish to see more like this!

Comment: And I stand by my words - a brilliant and beautiful puzzle.